# XML Display in android

Tags: android

I have one XML in my application. That XML file has different programs defined per day. I would like to display its contents in a `ListView` but depending on the day in the device, eg. if today is Friday then Friday's content should be displayed.

How can this be achieved?

Regards
Esan.

```
 <day id = "1001" name = "Monday" date = "22" month = "08" year = "2011"> 
    <program> 
        <id>10011</id> 
        <name></name> 
        <icon "http://"/> 
        <desc></desc> 
        <time start = "10.00 a.m" end = "01.00 p.m"/> 
        <url>rtsp://</url> 
    </program>
</day> 
<day id = "1002" name = "Tuesday" date = "23" month = "08" year = "2011"> 
    <program> 
        <id>10012</id> 
        <name></name> 
        <icon "http://"/> 
        <desc></desc> 
        <time start = "10.00 a.m" end = "01.00 p.m"/> 
        <url>rtsp://</url> 
    </program> 
</day>
```

Comment: can you add the xml code

Comment: Please check this<day id = "1001" name = "monday" date = "22" month = "08" year = "2011">
    <program>
     <id>10011</id>
  <name></name>
  <icon "http://"/>
  <desc></desc>
  <time start = "10.00 a.m" end = "01.00 p.m"/>
  <url>rtsp://</url>
   </program> 
  
  </day>
  
<day id = "1002" name = "Tuesday" date = "23" month = "08" year = "2011">
    <program>
     <id>10012</id>
  <name></name>
  <icon "http://"/>
  <desc></desc>
  <time start = "10.00 a.m" end = "01.00 p.m"/>
  <url>rtsp://</url>
   </program> 
  
  </day>

Comment: @Thilag: Please click on the edit link below your question and paste your code there instead of this place. It'll help others identify your code in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to parse the xml and add it to some sort of structure, and add that to an arraylist. Use this arraylist to populate ur layout.

Sample of structure is as below :

```
class DayValues {
        String id = "", name = "", date = "", month = "", year = "", icon = "", desc = "", start = "", end = "", url = "";

        public DayValues(String id, String name, String date, String month, String year, String icon, String desc, String start, String end, String url){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.date = date;
            this.month = month;
            this.year = year;
            this.icon = icon;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.url = url;
        }

        /**
         * @return the id
         */
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        /**
         * @param id the id to set
         */
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * @param name the name to set
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * @return the date
         */
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        /**
         * @param date the date to set
         */
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        /**
         * @return the month
         */
        public String getMonth() {
            return month;
        }

        /**
         * @param month the month to set
         */
        public void setMonth(String month) {
            this.month = month;
        }

        /**
         * @return the year
         */
        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        /**
         * @param year the year to set
         */
        public void setYear(String year) {
            this.year = year;
        }

        /**
         * @return the icon
         */
        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        /**
         * @param icon the icon to set
         */
        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        /**
         * @return the desc
         */
        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        /**
         * @param desc the desc to set
         */
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }

        /**
         * @return the start
         */
        public String getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        /**
         * @param start the start to set
         */
        public void setStart(String start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        /**
         * @return the end
         */
        public String getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        /**
         * @param end the end to set
         */
        public void setEnd(String end) {
            this.end = end;
        }

        /**
         * @return the url
         */
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        /**
         * @param url the url to set
         */
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

    }
```

Sample code to parse and add the data to arraylist :

private ArrayList arrDayDetails = new ArrayList();

```
private void parseXml(String response) {
    String id = "", name = "", date = "", month = "", year = "", icon = "", desc = "", start = "", end = "", url = "";
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser dayXml = factory.newPullParser();
        dayXml.setInput(new StringReader(response));

        // Get next parse event
        int eventType = dayXml.getEventType();
        String NodeValue = "";
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                NodeValue = dayXml.getName().trim();// Start of a Node
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                    id = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
                    name = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    date = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "date");
                    month = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "month");
                    year = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "year");
                }
                if(NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("time")){
                    start = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "start");
                    end = dayXml.getAttributeValue(null, "end");
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                    id = dayXml.getText();
                }
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("icon")) {
                    icon = dayXml.getText();
                }
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("desc")) {
                    desc = dayXml.getText();
                }
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                    url = dayXml.getText();
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                NodeValue = dayXml.getName().trim();// End of a Node
                if (NodeValue.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                    // Add the values to the arraylist.
                    DayValues dv = new DayValues(id, name, date, month, year, icon, desc, start, end, url);
                    arrDayDetails.add(dv);
                }

            }
            eventType = dayXml.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Adapter class that populates the listview should be like something below.
Here the layout has to be defined, and I'm assuming your list will contain the textview of  the you have parsed.

```
public class DayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Context mContext;

        public DayAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrDayDetails.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.daylist, null);
            }
            if (v != null) {
                // Logic to check day and display only those data.
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == getDay(arrDayDetails.get(position)
                            .getName())){
                    if (tvId != null) {
                        tvId.setText(arrDayDetails.get(position)
                                .getId());
                    }
                    if (tvName != null) {
                        tvName.setText(arrDayDetails.get(position)
                                .getName());
                    }
                }
            }
            return v;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle Exceptions
        }
        return null;
    }
}
    }
```

and code to get the date :

```
private int getDay(String day) {
        int dayNo = 0;
        try {
            if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Sunday"))
                dayNo = 1;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Monday"))
                dayNo = 2;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Tuesday"))
                dayNo = 3;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Wednesday"))
                dayNo = 4;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Thursday"))
                dayNo = 5;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Friday"))
                dayNo = 6;
            else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Saturday"))
                dayNo = 7;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
        return dayNo;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Swarna. i have some more question on this.in your code getView method you are using some variables like "arrDayDetails", "tvId" those variable for which class object. could you please help me this.

Comment: arrDayDetails  is an arraylist that contains the data you have parsed. (private ArrayList arrDayDetails = new ArrayList();). I have not added the layout xml. But if you create a view with say 2 textviews to display data in the listview, that has tvId and tvName, then it will get the data from this array and set the data to the textview in the getView method.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to implement a `switch` case where the case fetches for days.  This should in turn `setContentView` for that particular xml file corresponding to that day. Sync it with the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html%22Calendar%22).

Comment: can you give me some more details about this. i'm very new to android

Comment: Since the content only varies, I would suggest just updating the adapter based on the day.

Comment: Can you add your xml? The more details you provide in your question, the better the answers you receive can be.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for TODO list example.

Check [this](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-android-2-application-development/78435-needed-imports-chapter-2-do-list-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SAX XML PARSER](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse your xml and [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) abstract class to get the day of the week like this: `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` and the result must be 5 in your case.